# Animating UIBezierPath in custom UIView doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to animate `UIBezierPath` (from one path to another) in my custom `UIView` when user touches my view (touchesEnded).

My drawing code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [self createStartPath];
    [self createEndPath];

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddPath(currentContext, _startPath.CGPath);
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathStroke);

}

- (void) createStartPath
{
    _startPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [_startPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(18, 22.5)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18.38, 22.32) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(18.14, 22.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.29, 22.44)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18.32, 21.62) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(18.56, 22.11) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.53, 21.79)];
    [_startPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(6.78, 12)];
    [_startPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(18.32, 2.38)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18.38, 1.68) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(18.53, 2.21) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.56, 1.89)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(17.68, 1.62) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(18.21, 1.47) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(17.89, 1.44)];
     [_startPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(5.68, 11.62)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(5.5, 12) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.56, 11.71) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5.5, 11.85)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(5.68, 12.38) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.5, 12.15) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5.56, 12.29)];
    [_startPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(17.68, 22.38)];
    [_startPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18, 22.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(17.77, 22.46) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(17.89, 22.5)];
    [_startPath closePath];

    [self.fillColor setFill];

    [_startPath fill];
}

- (void) createEndPath
{

     _endPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [_endPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(6, 22.5)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(5.62, 22.32) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.86, 22.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5.71, 22.44)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(5.68, 21.62) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.44, 22.11) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5.47, 21.79)];
    [_endPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(17.22, 12)];
    [_endPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(5.68, 2.38)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(5.62, 1.68) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.47, 2.21) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5.44, 1.89)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(6.32, 1.62) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.79, 1.47) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(6.11, 1.44)];
    [_endPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(18.32, 11.62)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18.5, 12) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(18.44, 11.71) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.5, 11.85)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18.32, 12.38) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(18.5, 12.15) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.44, 12.29)];
    [_endPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(6.32, 22.38)];
    [_endPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(6, 22.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(6.23, 22.46) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(6.11, 22.5)];
    [_endPath closePath];

    [self.fillColor setFill];

    //[_endPath fill];
}
```

I start my animation here (would like to "morph" one path to another):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    CAShapeLayer * myLineShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    
    CABasicAnimation * pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    pathAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)[_startPath CGPath];
    pathAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)[_endPath CGPath];
    pathAnimation.duration = 3.0f;
    [myLineShapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"animationKey"];
}
```

I see the `startPath` and my `touchesEnded` is called, but nothing animates neither `endPath` is shown.

Comment: Seems like you didn't add `myLineShapeLayer ` as sublayer.

Comment: Thats correct (please add an answer). Now i have another problem that endPath disappears after animation stops. And also startPath remains on screen all the time. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your animation to work, please add your `myLineShapeLayer` as a sublayer of your view's `layer`:

For instance, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:myLineShapeLayer];
```

In order to be able to see the `endPath` still being persistently seen on the screen after the animation, we could first assign the `endPath` to the `path` property of the `CAShapeLayer`:

```
myLineShapeLayer.path = [endPath CGPath];
```

And thusly we animate without `toValue`:

```
CABasicAnimation * pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
pathAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)[_startPath CGPath];
pathAnimation.duration = 3.0f;
[myLineShapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"animationKey"];
```

The end effect of the animation would then remain on the screen after the animation.

Comment: Please think twice before rejecting edits [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8256290) as *not even improving the post a little bit*. Such edits **do** fix all issues with the post, and improve the readability of it.